# "403 - This web app is stopped" when deploying to Azure from VSCode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, deployment

I have a web app, [ironradio.org](https://www.ironradio.org), that I've deployed on Azure from VSCode. I've made some updates to the site and am now trying to deploy the newest version. Now when I try to deploy using this button:

[image: VSCode Azure extension cloud deployment button]

I get the error 403 - This web app is stopped in the output window:

[image: VSCode output window]

I've already deployed several versions of the site using the same method and it's never failed before. Also, the app is definitely not stopped because I can still browse to the site and it shows up.

My best guess as to what's going on is that I associated the App Service with a new resource group since the last deployment, so maybe VSCode isn't recognizing that? Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

I tried the link given in the error message, but it wasn't much help.

Comment: so you moved your app service to a new resource group ? yeah you would need to delete existing deployment method and add again

Comment: Yeah, so I switched it back to the old resource group and now the deployment seems to be working. I do want it on the other resource group though, so I'll have to figure out what to do in VSCode to make that work. I'm pretty new to Azure and the Azure App Service extension so I'm a little confused.

Comment: re follow this tuturial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vscode?view=aspnetcore-5.0. You webapp should appear in a different resource group once moved

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft foreseen this type of error and how it can affected its customers greatly and this is why the deployment slot is for you.

Firstly, you have to delete the app and reupload again except you set up continuous deployment which work mostly with GitHub and other version control platforms.

Apart from this, I will suggest you check out the deployment slot docs. It’s very simple and easy to use

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots